# Trimming a string help

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, string

I have an object array that is being passed and then split up into different variables. The problem is, one of the variables is supposed to be a number/a string, whatever, but it is arriving with all these funky characters on the beginning and end of the number. I set up a break point so I could see the value, it is this:
"\"91\""

or really, without the outer quotations since those are just for identification, it's
\"91\"

I tried doing a trimstart and trimend like so:
whateverobjarray.variablename.TrimStart('"', '/');
whateverobjarray.variablenameTrimEnd('"', '/');

I forgot if it was a / or \ slash...so it obviously didn't get the backslash...but it also didn't remove the quotes at the beginning or end either. The '\' doesn't seem to work as it still thinks anything after that is part of the characters I'm trying to get rid of.

What is the proper syntax for doing this in my situation where I just want the number...also it needs to work if the number is 1, 2, or 3 digits. Do I have to cast it as a string or some type of number first? HELP!!! It's driving me crazy!

*edit*
I also tried this
char[] trimArray = { '"', '\'', '/' };
whateverobjarray.variablename.TrimStart(trimArray);
whateverobjarray.variablename.TrimEnd(trimArray);

Didn't take anything off either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I think the backslash is just escaping the quotes, so you'll want to trim `\"`. Secondly, since strings are immutable, calling variablename.TrimStart() doesn't actually change the value of that variable. You have to say:

```
obj.MyString = obj.MyString.Trim('"');
```

Comment: OP should also just use `Trim` rather than both `TrimStart` and `TrimEnd`.

Comment: Thanks, I used a hybrid of my char trim array and your answer, I forgot I have to set it equal to the call. Thanks for your help. I may also try trim like stated, but for now it works and I think I understand what was going on with the backslash.

Comment: @Nard Dog: I definitely recommend trim. String operations can be kind of expensive, and Trim will do in one pass what TrimStart and TrimEnd will take two to do. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

These look like escaped characters, so each \" is a single character. You could do a replace to remove the characters. However, your best bet is to get a handle on [character escaping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691087%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in C# and it may all click into place.

try

```
variablename.Replace("\"","");
```

Comment: I learn best through example, I see once, then I learn. I appreciate your input though. I was hoping someone could show me a solution, then I could look up why it works on my own.